# Sales and Delivery quantities of items delivered 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables

delivery:
dnum (number)
,dqty
,dname
,iname (item name)
...

sale:
snum
,sqty
,iname
,dname

I'd like to find the following:

sale item, delivery item ,total sales quantity (sum(sqty)) ,total delivery quantity (sum(dqty)), sale to delivery ratio ( sum(sqty) / sum(dqty))

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Calculate sums in separate subqueries then join.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Pls also show what you have tried. Because they looks like ismple aggregate functions.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Why would you want rows where the items are different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you want one item per row in the result set.  You can use `union all` and `group by`:

```
select iname, sum(sqty), sum(dqty),
       sum(sqty) / nullif(sum(dqty), 0) as ratio
from ((select iname, sqty, 0 as dqty
       from sales
      ) union all
      (select iname, 0, dqty
       from delivery
      )
     ) ds
group by iname;
```

Comment: This worked! Was having issues with the union all